# Suppose $\{f_n\}$ are a sequence of non negative measurable functions and $f_n\to f$ point wise, and $\int f=\lim \int f_n$

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

I know the question has been asked but their proofs arent whats on my mind, and I want to know where is the flaw in my proof because I cant seem to find it.

Suppose $\{f_n\}$ are a sequence of non negative measurable functions and $f_n\to f$ point wise, and $\int f=\lim \int f_n<\infty$ show that $\int_E f=\lim \int_E f_n$. where $E$ is measurable.

Update:

We know that $\lim \int f_n=\int f$ then $\lim \sup \int f_n =\lim \inf \int f_n$. Also $\int f=\int_E f+ \int_{E^c} f$ then we have the following,
\begin{align*}
\int_E f =\int f-\int_{E^c}f&\geq \int f-\lim \sup \int_{E^c} f_n \text{ by fatou lemma}
\\&= \lim \sup \int f-\lim \sup \int_{E^c}f_n
\\&=\limsup (\int f-\int_{E^c}f_n)=\limsup \int_E f_n 
\end{align*}

Conversely, by faout's lemma again $$\int_E f=\int f \chi_E \leq \liminf \int f_n \chi_E=\liminf \int_E f$$

Thank you for your help!

Comment: How do you find that $0\leqslant \int_E f_n-\int_E f$ ? For exmaple, if $E=[0,1]$ and $f_n = 1-1/n$ then...

Comment: if $\int f\ge \int_E f$ then you cannot say that $-\int f\ge -\int_E f.$

Comment: Thanks, so i must try to work my way through fatou's lemma.